# Conflicting dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a conflicting dependency:

```
Gem A depends on Gem B 2.0
```

But

```
Gem C depends on Gem B 1.5
```

Should I force like this:

```
gem 'B', '~> 1.5'
```

All of my other gems are using Gem B 2.5 (the latet version) without problem though, so can I do something like this in my Gemfile?:

```
gem 'B' # 2.5

gem 'A', dependency: 'b 2.0'
gem 'C', dependency: 'b 1.5'

# gems happily use B 2.5
```

Update, my exact problem:

```
rails-observers(>=0) ruby
   activemodel(~> 4.0)

jquery-scrollto-rails(>=) ruby
   activemodel(~> 3.1.0)
```

My gemfile isn't enfocring any dependencies at all. No version number option.

```
bundle install
```

completes okay but

```
bundle update
```

results in the error above

Comment: Could you specify what your exact problem is? I would assume you can just omit the version numbers altogether and let Bundler handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Fork jquery-scrollto-rails on github and upgrade the version. Run it's testsuite. If it runs make a pull request and until it's accepted use your version from github.

If it's not running, then -

Don't complain, fix ;)

**Edit**

They have a newer version which supports railties 3 < 5
Add this to your Gemfile

```
 gem 'jquery-scrollto-rails', '~> 1.4.3'
```

Then run `$ bundle install`

See [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-scrollto-rails/versions/1.4.3)

**NOTE:**

I recommend always using version specifications in your Gemfile. The most optimistic strategy is just by fixing them to the minor version e.g `gem 'jquery-scrollto-rails', '~> 1.4'`. This is a tremendious help for bundler, which has an np-complete problem to solve. In theory according to Semver there should be no incompatible changes on minor version updates and you could have fixed your problem just by running `$ bundle update`. A lot of gems do follow this convention, but there are blacksheeps